# Reduce MySQL request time with Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I use `Codeigniter 3.1.11` and have some code which makes one big query to `MySQL` with an array. The time of a query with a limit of `30000` is about `9` seconds.

How can I reduce the request time? Maybe by using some indexes on my table, or do you know another method? If I need to use indexes, what indexes would I need to use and how can I use these indexes in my query on `Codeigniter`?

Code from model:

```php
function rows_update() {
$query = $this->db->order_by('rating', 'DESC')->get_where('members', 'game_rating_and_balance_update_last_time <= now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY', '30000', '0'); 
$arrUpdateBatchData = [];

while ($row = $query->unbuffered_row('array'))
    {
      // some code here

                $arrUpdateData = [
                'UserID' => $row['UserID'], 
                'game_vault_balance' => $new_game_vault_balance,
                'game_available_balance' => $new_game_available_balance,
                'rating' => $rating_member,
                'game_rating_and_balance_update_last_time' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                ];
            
            $arrUpdateBatchData[] = $arrUpdateData;

        if (count($arrUpdateBatchData) > 500)
        {
            $this->db->update_batch('members', $arrUpdateBatchData, 'UserID');
            $arrUpdateBatchData = [];
        }       
    }

    //update last items
    if (count($arrUpdateBatchData) > 0)
    {
        $this->db->update_batch('members', $arrUpdateBatchData, 'UserID');
        $arrUpdateBatchData = [];
    }
    return;    
}
```

Raw query to MySQL with update_batch (I simply write only one row from an array):

```
UPDATE members SET game_vault_balance = CASE WHEN UserID = '9915075' THEN 803.60516004772 ELSE game_vault_balance END, game_available_balance = CASE WHEN UserID = '9915075' THEN 4.1253850908788 ELSE game_available_balance END, rating = CASE WHEN UserID = '9915075' THEN 0.24 ELSE rating END, game_rating_and_balance_update_last_time = CASE WHEN UserID = '9915075' THEN '2020-07-24 22:00:36' ELSE game_rating_and_balance_update_last_time END WHERE UserID IN('9915075')
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `UserID` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `telegram_id` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rating` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `game_vault_balance` decimal(32,8) DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `game_available_balance` decimal(32,8) DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `game_rating_and_balance_update_last_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Indexes of this table:

```
ALTER TABLE `members`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ADD UNIQUE KEY `UserID` (`UserID`) USING BTREE;
```

`AUTO_INCREMENT` for the `members` table:

```
ALTER TABLE `members`
MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: How do you calculate the new values that you would like to save to the members table? Is that something you could calculate in sql? Is the speed of the select query acceptable?

Comment: @Shadow, `$new_game_vault_balance`, `$game_available_balance` and `$rating_member` I'm calculate in PHP. How can I make calculations in SQL in my case with array? I didn't measure the speed of select query. How can I do it in my case?

Comment: Measuring the spped of your select query: run the query in your favourite mysql IDE that you use and it will tell you the speed. Calculations on array in sql: you would not calculate on an array in sql, you would do the calculation on the member records in scope. By pushing the calculations into sql, you would have a single update statement.

Comment: There's something I don't understand. You say `select` statements are taking very long to process, but the code samples you provide are for `update` statements. Which one is it? (Select and update performance issues are addressed differently). FWIW limiting the output won't help much, as it won't limit the amount of processing that needs to be done by the database engine, only how much of the resultset is returned

Comment: @JavierLarroulet, I don't say that `select` are taking very long process. I suppose that `update` are taking a long process, but I don't know. Therefore, I have attached my code to my post so that you can look at it and say more precisely what the problem is. If you know how to solve a problem or you have a specific solution, please write it, maybe it will help.